# Ideal way to implement cleanup method in Python

Tags: python, code-cleanup

Re-writing to make it more clear, but I believe Clark J got it. I have file with content like this:

```
class tests:

    def test1(self):
        create something1

    def test2(self):
        create something2
    .
    .
    .
    .

    def test19(self):
        cleanup something1

    def test20(self):
        cleanup something2
```

If test1 or test2 fails, it is leaving behind something1, something2. Wondering if using "try: finally:" is ok in below style so that test19 and test20 runs everytime before program quits or if there is a more ideal way of doing that differently. Basically my goal if to make sure that test19 and test20 are always run before program quits incase of failures in other tests. Thanks.

```
class tests:

    try:

        def test1(self):
            create something1

        def test2(self):
            create something2
        .
        .
        .
        .

    finally:

        def test19(self):
            cleanup something1

        def test20(self):
            cleanup something2
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't see a reason why you couldn't use try finally blocks.

Alternatively you could use the [atexit](https://docs.python.org/3.2/library/atexit.html) module. Which runs registered functions after your program has finished terminating. It is part of the standard lib in python 2 and python 3.

```
import atexit

@atexit.register   #decorator call only works for functions without args
def function_to_run_on_exit():
    print ("doing some awesome teardown and cleanup")

def exit_function_with_args(foo, bar):
    print("cleaning up {} and {}").format(foo, bar))



atexit.register(exit_function_with_args, 'my foo', 'my bar')
```